# Error: Transport endpoint is not connected (Python Sockets)

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, chat

I'm trying to create a simple chat application using sockets in Python (with threads). Application is simple client has to threads one to send data and another to receive. Server has to two threads one to accept client connection and another to broadcast the message. But on running the below code, I'm getting error message

> Transport endpoint is not connected

[image]

Can anybody tell me why I'm getting this error

Client

```
import socket, threading

def send():
    msg = raw_input('Me > ')
    cli_sock.send(msg)

def receive():
    data = cli_sock.recv(4096)
    print('> '+ str(data))

if __name__ == "__main__":   
    # socket
    cli_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # connect
    HOST = 'localhost'
    PORT = 5028
    cli_sock.connect((HOST, PORT))     
    print('Connected to remote host...')

    thread_send = threading.Thread(target = send)
    thread_send.start()

    thread_receive = threading.Thread(target = receive)
    thread_receive.start()
```

Server

```
import socket, threading

def accept_client():
    while True:
        #accept    
        cli_sock, cli_add = ser_sock.accept()
        CONNECTION_LIST.append(cli_sock)
        print('Client (%s, %s) connected' % cli_add)

def broadcast_data():
    while True:
        data = ser_sock.recv(4096)
        for csock in CONNECTION_LIST:
            try:
                csock.send(data)
            except Exception as x:
                print(x.message)
                cli_sock.close()
                CONNECTION_LIST.remove(cli_sock)

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    CONNECTION_LIST = []

    # socket
    ser_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # bind
    HOST = 'localhost'
    PORT = 5028
    ser_sock.bind((HOST, PORT))

    # listen        
    ser_sock.listen(1)
    print('Chat server started on port : ' + str(PORT))

    thread_ac = threading.Thread(target = accept_client)
    thread_ac.start()

    thread_bd = threading.Thread(target = broadcast_data)
    thread_bd.start()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using server sockets incorrectly. You cannot `recv` on server sockets, instead you [`accept`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.accept) connections on them; `accept` returns the actual connection socket:

```
ser_sock.listen(1)
sock, addr = ser_sock.accept()

print('Got connection from {}'.format(addr))

# only this *connection* socket can receive!
data = sock.recv(4096)
```